# Photoshop in game development

Tags: adobe-photoshop, games, affinity-designer

I've always used pre-made assets from the unity store so far but since I'll probably move on to making my own models and textures et cetera I was wondering about the place of photoshop in game / asset development. I ask because I mostly develop on Mac and I was looking into Affinity Photo as my future editor of choice (I know about GIMP, I've used it in the past but I just don't like it). *Photo* is only 50$ compared to the awful software-as-a-service model of Photoshop.

So have you heard of Affinity Photo? What are the features necessary for making assets and textures?

Any advice or insight is welcome, thanks in advance.

---

I'm new here, so in doubt I've also posted this question to the gamedev stack, just in case.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please dont cross post across stackexhange sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it all really depends on what you do with your image editor. Photoshop certainly has features. Some of these features are useful in your context (scripting engine, but then you can get same from gimp for free) some features are useful only for print productions, text layout etc.

What is really comes down to is if you can make graphics. Very very far behind comes and usability of the software of your choice. Quite rarely will you find that the software in question is the limiting factor. After all a good carpenter never (or at least seldom) blames his tools. No graphics app actually makes you good at making game assets. There's nothing that stops you making top notch images with a text editor.